# JQuery .forEach not supported in IE8. Is there a work around?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code block working in IE9 correctly

```
data.forEach(function loadClips(value) {
    //console.log("URL  of the show is " + value.Images[0].Url);
    var href = '/video/player.aspx?vid=' + value.Id;
    var title = value.ShortDesc;


 "</a></li>");                         


})
```

But it doesn't work in IE8. Instead of .forEach, i tried .each(), it doesn't work either. Any ideas on what the correct solution should be? many thanks

Comment: `forEach` isn't part of jQuery; it's a Javascript `Array` method that wasn't available in earlier JS versions. That, and the fact that `.each()` isn't working, makes me think you have a plain JS array there, not a jQuery object. Where did `data` come from?

Comment: var data = d.Items. I believe it is an array maybe

Answer (score 2):

This should do it (don't forget the last semi-colon)

```
 $.each(data, function loadClips(value) {
    //console.log("URL  of the show is " + value.Images[0].Url);
    var href = '/video/player.aspx?vid=' + value.Id;
    var title = value.ShortDesc;


 "</a></li>");                         


});
```

Comment: I guess you meant: `$.each(data, function(){...});`

Comment: ... or `$(data).each( ... )`, which is less reliable across jQuery versions. You definitely *don't* mean to use `'data'` as a string, as the edit stands right now.

Comment: no, that didn't quite work using $.each, the "value" came up as undefined. Because data is actually an array. I think in order to make it work, I cannot use the .forEach anymore. I will have to iterate it through a normal loop

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` is not a jQuery function. See support for [Array.prototype.forEach](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.forEach).

Instead, you can use

`$(array).each(function (index, item) { doSomething(item); });`

[See documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: You shouldn't use `$.fn.each()` on array, only on array like object as jq set

Comment: Yes, I shouldn´t, but I can use `$.fn.each` on any array

Comment: Just misread question because data seems to be a matched set of elements, but not sure what it is indeed, array of DOM nodes, DOM node list, or what. But that's said, using a method not specifiaclly set to be used on specific element can give not expected result. In jQuery DOC: `Description: Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.`

Answer (score 1):

i just iterate it through a traditional for loop, as supposed to forEach and that worked for IE8